# Checkbox to submit a value different from 1/0 or true/false on check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have **checkbox** input field where

```
value = {$variable} // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....
```

How to make it so that the checkbox **always** on check and uncheck to submit the value to the db?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add_value[]" id="add-value" value="{$variable}">
```

The form needs to submit **only** unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: You cannot do that unless you write your own JavaScript code to gather the form field states and construct your own parameters. Browsers do not submit checkbox field parameters when the checkboxes are not checked.

Comment: How do I do the Javascript. I already submit and add it to the db. The tricky part is to do it on the uncheck action! Humm hummm

Comment: Why does the checkbox matter if it always submits the same value regardless of whether or not it's checked?

Comment: When unchecked it doesn't submit anything. Or at leas I can't get it to submit whats in the value=. I need it to do so as i have other attributes in the form that need to be updated on this submission.

Comment: Before checkbox add input hidden with same name as checkbox is - if not checked, value will be read from hidden input.

Comment: Let me try this black magic!

Comment: YES, adding a hidden input worked. Why sometimes simple things get so much time to get to them!

Comment: Now it submits all checkboxes I need to submit only the ones that have been unchecked! I guess I have to look into Javascript for this?